# analyze a file's fragmentation in Windows 7

Tags: c#, c++, windows-7

Is there a way that I can determine the fragmentation of a single file via programmatic means?  For example, is there some type of file system API that I can tap into to retrieve this type of information?

Comment: The MSDN topic [Defragmenting Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) covers this. It sounds like you are specifically looking for [`FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Jeffrey Wall has [some C# wrapper classes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx).

Comment: @Raymond: You should make that an answer, I guess.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Yes, that would be an answer I would accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just copy and pasting [Raymond's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416402/analyze-a-files-fragmentation-in-windows-7#comment13439839_10416402) from the comments, so I've marked it as a **community wiki answer**.

For C/C++, use [FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For C#, use [these wrapper classes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good C# wrapper for the FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffrey_wall/archive/2004/09/13/229137.aspx

This wrapper calls the control code to return back a list of an object that defines where each file is on disk.

You probably want the GetFileMap method to retrieve this information.